# Difference in the way Authentication is done by S3 and SWIFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openstack, openstack-swift

The question is simple here. As the title suggests, i want to know how the auth gets donein case of s3 and SWIFT. I see that in case of SWIFT, there was a mention that API access key is obtained from authentication service you chose when installing. What Authentication service are we talking about here?

And i keep hearing that the Swift API is probably best to talk to given they’ve tried to separate it from an implementation. Not sure what they mean by this.

For S3 is looked up to the below wiki for reference:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: https://github.com/fujita/swift3  you might check out this handy s3 compatability api for swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What differentiates Swift with authentication is one can use more than one authentication platform. One can implement this using the "Auth Middleware"

The developer guide http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_auth.htmlexplains about same here.

Hope it helps.